# spring boot WebTestClient throws "No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClient' available"

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, spring-webtestclient

Several people have had similar problems, but what was marked as a solution for them did not solve the problem for me.

Pom.xml:

```
:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
:
```

CustomerControllerTest2.java

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.reactive.AutoConfigureWebTestClient;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClient;

import static org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.ACCEPT;
import static org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON;
import static org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE;

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
public class CustomerControllerTest2 {

    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient webTestClient;

    @Test
    void shouldReturnManyCustomers(){
        this.webTestClient
                .get()
                .uri("/customers")
                .header(ACCEPT,APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus()
                .is2xxSuccessful()
                .expectHeader()
                .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                .expectBody()
                .jsonPath("$.length()").isNumber()
                .jsonPath("$[0].id").isEqualTo(1);
    }
}
```

According to others, the solution is to add "@AutoConfigureWebTestClient" and "@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)"

But this did not help.

When I use TestRestTemplate I have no issues, e.g. the below works out of the box:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment;
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate;
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.server.LocalServerPort;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class CustomerControllerTest {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    void greetingShouldReturnDefaultMessage() throws Exception {
        assertThat(this.restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:" + port + "/customers",
                String.class)).contains("user@haha.com");

    }

}
```

These docs:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.testing.spring-boot-applications.with-running-server

say the following will work:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class MyRandomPortWebTestClientTests {

    @Test
    void exampleTest(@Autowired WebTestClient webClient) {
        webClient
            .get().uri("/")
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus().isOk()
            .expectBody(String.class).isEqualTo("Hello World");
    }

}
```

But this also gives the same "No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClient' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate."

Interestingly, if I run "mvn test" both TestRestTemplate and TesWebClient tests work. If I run the tests using intellij, it fails.  In intellij, it doesnt seem to know how to run anything by default, but there is an "All in package" run configuration under junit which is the only way I can see to run the tests, and this runs all TestRestTemplate tests no problem, but all WebTestClient basted tests fails with the no qualifying bean issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@AutoConfigureWebTestClient` is intended for use with a mock web environment. From its javadoc:

> Annotation that can be applied to a test class to enable a `WebTestClient` that is bound directly to the application. Tests do not rely upon an HTTP server and use mock requests and responses.

You are contradicting this by using `@AutoConfigureWebTestClient` and `webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT` in combination. Instead, you could use `@SpringBootTest` with its default, mock web environment:

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
public class CustomerControllerTest {
```

You can learn more about this in the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.testing.spring-boot-applications.with-mock-environment).

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to get it working without any mocking - i.e. an integration test which hits the local server.  Originally I had it without "@AutoConfigureWebTestClient" but I still get the error.

Comment: it seems to be an intellij issue. If I run from termina "mvn test" it works. But if I use the intellij run configuration under JUNIT "run all in project" it runs the TestRestTemplate based tests no problem, but fails to run any TestWebClient based tests with this error.  If you cant run tests from intellij, and have to open a terminal each time, its a pain.